# How to remove entries using a model function?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I am working on a rails assignment that wants a remove_entry method within the model and a working test for remove_entry. I am having some trouble making the test pass. Does anyone have any recommendations on how to define the remove_entry method within addressbook.rb and also how to write the the test in entry_spec.rb?

Entry.rb:

```
#Load a library called entry.rb
require_relative "entry.rb"

class AddressBook
  attr_accessor :entries

  def initialize
    @entries = []
  end

  def add_entry(name, phone, email)
    #Create a variable index to store
    index = 0
    @entries.each do |entry|
      if name < entry.name
        break
      end
      index += 1
    end

    @entries.insert(index,Entry.new(name,phone,email))
  end

  def remove_entry(entry)
    @entries.destroy(entry)
  end
end
```

Address Book Spec:

```
RSpec.describe AddressBook do
  context "attributes" do
    it "should respond to entries" do
      book = AddressBook.new
      expect(book).to respond_to(:entries)
    end
    it "should initialize entries as an array" do
       book = AddressBook.new
       expect(book.entries).to be_a(Array)
     end

     it "should initialize entries as empty" do
       book = AddressBook.new
       expect(book.entries.size).to eq 0
     end
  end

  context ".add_entry" do
    it "adds only one entry to the address book" do
      book = AddressBook.new
      book.add_entry('Ada Lovelace', '010.012.1815', 'augusta.king@lovelace.com')

      expect(book.entries.size).to eq 1
    end

    it "adds the correct information to entries" do
       book = AddressBook.new
       book.add_entry('Ada Lovelace', '010.012.1815', 'augusta.king@lovelace.com')
       new_entry = book.entries[0]

       expect(new_entry.name).to eq 'Ada Lovelace'
       expect(new_entry.phone_number).to eq '010.012.1815'
       expect(new_entry.email).to eq 'augusta.king@lovelace.com'
    end
  end

  context ".remove_entry" do
    it "deletes one entry of the address book" do
      book.entries.delete_entry(entry)
      expect(book.entries.size).to eq 0
    end
  end
end
```

I also have an entry.rb and entry_spec.rb but I believe they remove method would be in address book, correct? Since the entry is being removed from that model. Any clarification would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right that the `remove_entry` method should be in `AddressBook` since it is modifying the address book's `entries` collection (and the `Entry` class should know nothing about `AddressBook` or its internals).

However, because your `add_entry` method doesn't expose the `Entry` class you'll want to make `remove_entry` work the same way, perhaps finding entries by email (which should be unique, as opposed to the name which might not be unique). So you could do something like this:

```
def remove_entry(email)
  @entries.delete_if {|entry| entry.email == email}
end
```

To test this method you would then do something like this:

```
context ".remove_entry" do
  it "deletes one entry of the address book" do
    book = AddressBook.new
    book.add_entry('Ada Lovelace', '010.012.1815', 'augusta.king@lovelace.com')

    book.delete_entry('augusta.king@lovelace.com')
    expect(book.entries.size).to eq(0)
  end
end
```